# Open URL in default internal browser through inappbrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, browser, inappbrowser

I have an app with Cordova that execute InAppBrowser to open a webapp, and I need open an URL in default internal browser.

I don't need open the URL inside the inappbrowser. I need since inappbrowser launch a 'code' and open (for example: chrome) and open the URL, but the app need to be in the background. I will be 2 app chrome (with a page load) and my cordova app.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't get your question completely, do you want to open an URL from your app in the default browser of the device?

Comment: @Ujjwal I need open an URL from inappbrowser in default browser

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<your URL>"]];
```

Comment: This code not found for me. I need a solution for both system (Android and IOS). I launch the inappbrowser with the next code
`app.window = window.open(url, "_self");`

Comment: The above code is for iOS only. If you want to get the same thing work for both the platforms i.e. iOS and android, you can write your own custom plugin which would have both platform's native code.